# JavaFX Apply css to TableRows only if they are :enabled

Tags: java, css, javafx

Assuming that JavaFX CSS doesn't support the `:enabled` based on [JavaFX 8 Oracle CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control) how i can do the below?

[Hover and Active only when not disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600687/hover-and-active-only-when-not-disabled#11600702)

---

A `TableView` exists where i am applying some kind of css :

```
.table-row-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color:orange;
}

.table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color:purple;
}
```

---

**I want the above to be done ( only ) when the `TableRow` is enabled**.

**So** i modified the code including `:enabled` pseudo element but nothing works now:

```
.table-row-cell:hover:enabled {
    -fx-background-color:orange;
}

.table-row-cell:focused:enabled {
    -fx-background-color:purple;
}
```

---

**Finally some small questions:**

1)How i can combine **:hover** with **:disabled** or **:enabled**?

```
->[ apply **:hover** only if the `Table-Row|Cell` is enabled. ]
```

2)Does JavaFX css supports **:enabled**?

---

**Last but not least**:

After doing several tests on the code above i came to [youtu.be/l7Pbz2l2wjE?t=138](http://youtu.be/l7Pbz2l2wjE?t=138) this result.

Comment: Can you put the code of your table ? I will try to help you !

Comment: @Bo Halim The code is working fine . Imagine that it is the same code from JavaFX Oracle tutorial. The css is the problem. The first part is working well but when i try to use `:enabled` pseudo class is not working . Maybe cause it is not supported . But i dont know how to do what i am asking on the title...

Comment: @Bo Halim You can use the code from the answer here where you have some rows disabled and some enabled  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607144/javafx-how-to-disable-a-row-in-a-tableview

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I'm really sleepy so my mind doesn't really work but isn't this the default behavior? I ran a sample code using your css and when a row is disabled, hovering and selection don't change its background color. Am I making a mistake and should really go to sleep?

Comment: @omid xaxaxa Yeah it doesn't work at all . Even when the rows are enabled...Of course i am talking about the `:enabled` . As about the `first part of code` sometimes it changes the background sometimes not , if you do a little bit more testing. Finally if you are really sleepy this will wake you up ( https://youtu.be/l7Pbz2l2wjE?t=138 )

Comment: video was perfect :)) But I tested my code(http://pastebin.com/VNZLKhZ3) again with your first css and it works as you expect. Css only gets applied when row is enabled, I don't know why it doesn't work for you, confusing! Anyway maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350099/programmatically-change-the-tableview-row-appearance

Comment: If the row is disabled, why will it even have focus or hover event in the first place? Isn't this contradicts with disable property?

Comment: @Harshita Sethi Unfortunately it doesn't work like this . I have an answer showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution using `:disabled` was the below:

As you can clearly see the row can be `focused` but `no hovered` and even `selected` even if it is `:disabled`.

---

Solution number 1 with `:disabled`(faster):

```
 /* .table-row-cell */

.table-row-cell:disabled{
    -fx-opacity:0.5;
}

.table-row-cell .text{
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-fill: black ;
} 

.table-row-cell:focused .text {
     -fx-fill: white ;
}

.table-row-cell:focused{
    -fx-background-color:purple;
}

.table-row-cell:focused:disabled{ /* focused+disabled */
    -fx-background-color:blue;
}

.table-row-cell:hover{
    -fx-background-color:magenta;
}
```

---

Solution number 2 based on the answer of [Harshita Sethi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391517/harshita-sethi) using a `pseudoclass`:

```
PseudoClass enableRowClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("enabled-row");

setRowFactory(tv -> {
                TableRow<Media> row = new TableRow<>();

                // use EasyBind to access the valueProperty of the itemProperty
                // of the cell:
                row.disableProperty().bind(
                        // start at itemProperty of row
                        EasyBind.select(row.itemProperty())
                                // map to fileExistsProperty[a boolean] of item, if item
                                // non-null
                                .selectObject(Media::fileExistsProperty)
                                // map to BooleanBinding checking if false
                                .map(x -> x.booleanValue() == false)
                                // value to use if item was null
                                .orElse(false));

  //This line of code is the idea of the `Harshita Sethi` modified a little bit to not use a changelistener
  row.pseudoClassStateChanged(enableRowClass, !row.disabledProperty().get());

    return row;
 });
```

- And of course the **.css**(mention that it doesn't produce the exact
  as the solution 1 cause it is missing some lines ;) :

  ```
  .table-row-cell:enabled-row:hover .table-cell {
      -fx-background-color: purple;

  }

  .table-row-cell:enabled-row:focused .table-cell {
      -fx-background-color: orange;

  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I reversed your idea, instead of trying to find who is `enabled` , why not look for the opposite (which is `disabled`) and apply a fixed style, so that it does not change when the cursor enters the boundaries :

```
     .table-row-cell{

     -fx-background-color:red;

     }

     .table-row-cell:disabled{

     -fx-background-color:red; //Here you can define a fixed style 
                               //  or similar to the normal state

     }

     .table-row-cell:focused:disabled .text{

       -fx-fill: red; // Here you define the color of the text

     }

     .table-row-cell:hover{

     -fx-background-color:blue;

     }
```

Hope this will help you, and sorry if I misunderstood!!

Comment: Thanks for the try but what i want is : Imagine this code here `.table-row-cell:focused {
    -fx-background-color:purple;
}` i want this to be applied only and only if the `TableRow` is not disabled . The code you have given doesn't or it maybe helps but i have to write double amount of code to achieve it :)  , but i appreciate the effort. I have edited the question to be more simple...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `javafx.css.PseudoClass` to change the styling of particular rows. Following is an example on how to use `PseudoClass`.

**JavaFx code**

```
PseudoClass enableRowClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("enabled-row");
// A row factory that returns a row that disables itself whenever the
// item it displays has a value less than 5:
table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.selectInteger(row.itemProperty(), "value")
                    .lessThan(5));


    row.itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Item>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Item> observable, Item oldValue, Item newValue) {
            try {
                //Applying pseudoclass to only those rows which are enabled.
                // The condition is the reverse of the condition used to disable a row.
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(enableRowClass, newValue.getValue() >= 5);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
        }
    });
    return row;
});
```

**Css :**

```
.table-row-cell:enabled-row:hover .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: purple;

}

.table-row-cell:enabled-row:focused .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: orange;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea i used something similar to create a different kind of solution ;)

Comment: The answer i added is using your idea without a `ChangeListener` .

Comment: You may need the `ChangeListener`, to apply the pseudoclass dynamically, if due to dynamic data change your row is enable/disabled, you wont get the same css style on the newly enabled/disabled row without `ChangeListener.`